# How to add an external library to nx manually

Tags: angular, shared-libraries, nrwl, nomachine-nx, nx.dev

I am using [nx.dev](http://nx.dev/) for a new application.

I generated a library for my application, now I want to use this library adding in NX applications

> how to import library in project NX

Comment: what package manager you are using? yarn or npm?

Comment: I use @npm!!!!!

Comment: I have a sample application just for test this application generated library and i want to add in workspace nx

Comment: yes nx.dev for doing workspace with multiple applications